# Virtualization - graphics card needed?

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I'm planning to set up a server just for running several (> 5) virtual machines on linux using KVM. No screen attached to a graphics card needed at this stage.

Therefore I'm wondering if the used physical graphics card has any impact for the virtual machines? Should I use a standard graphics card with 1024MB+ ram or does a very low budget graphics card <= 128MB ram last?

In general: Does KVM use the graphics card at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible to get away with no graphics card at all, using only the console port (COM port), SSH, etc for administration. This is sufficient for most applications, it's still somewhat uncommon for VMs to "require" a graphics card. Certain situations do warrant passing a graphics card through to a VM however.

Comment: wouldn't it be better for the vm's to use the graphics card, for example to use aero in windows 7?

Comment: @nexus "Aero in Windows 7"?  What kind of server are you running here!? :D

Comment: @Kevin running Windows7 in a virtual machine.

Comment: The answer to the question you asked was "Does KVM require a graphics card." The answer is no. If your guests require GPU or other graphics capabilities, then that's a different question.

Comment: @mfinni so let's say I run Windows 7 or a ubuntu with gnome and I want to experience Aero style, transparency of windows and so forth. Does it then require a graphics card on the host, where KVM is installed?

Comment: Your new question has veered fairly well out of SF into SU territory; sounds like this is for home/personal use?

Comment: @mfinni In my opinion it's still the same question: «[...] if the used physical graphics card has any impact for the virtual machines?» and no it's not for home/personal.

Comment: @nexus It depends on the software. Aero does not require a graphics card on the server. RemoteFX does however. Obviously if you're going to be connecting to the VM from the "server" box then you'll need a graphics card; else the monitor would have nothing to plug into... But as to what card you need for what software, the only answer I can provide is "I depends on what you're running". Even RemoteFX has different graphics card requirements for different configurations.

Comment: @ChrisS for sure I need a graphics card if I'm going to connect to the VM from the server box. But it's interesting that for example Aero does not require one. I could have imagined that everything what has to produce screen images needs a GPU as a peripheral device or a unit in the CPU.